# page not found error error on codeigniter database creation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

am experiencing an error "The requested URL /county/migration was not found on this server." as was trying to create database and tables using he migration in codeigniter framework
 please help

Answer (score 0):

check if you have enable `requested` and `rewrite` module in apache and check you have put `.htaccess` file properly.